# How to echo data from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
[first_information] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 12
    )

[rows] => 1
[0] => Array
    (
        [data_1] => 1
        [data_2] => 2
        [data_3] => 3
        [data_4] => 4
        [data_5] => 5
    )
```

)

How am I supposed to show only the [first_information] content's.

I have tried with this code

```
foreach($row['first_information'] as $first)  
   echo $first;
```

But shows only '12' which is the second element of the array.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That should work, (`foreach($row['first_information'] as $first) {echo $first;}`). Are you 100% sure your array looks like that?

Comment: SOLVED! echo $row['first_information'][0].' '.$row['first_information'][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something wrong (not shown in question, probably wrong var). The code below working as expected (http://codepad.org/NDxhEBdY):

```
$row = array(
    'first_information' => Array(10,12),
    'rows' => 1,
     0 => Array(
        'data_1' => 1,
        'data_2' => 2,
        'data_3' => 3,
        'data_4' => 4,
        'data_5' => 5
    )
);

foreach($row['first_information'] as $first)  
    echo $first;
```